# How to fix this code in order for it to average similarities based on usernames?

Tags: python-3.x, data-science

I'm using Python 3.6 and running into a problem. I'll explain. I have a dataframe called test_data_sample, that has two variables, "user" and "text". There are two different users but each user has written several texts. Below is an example:

```
User  Text
user1 legit thank later
user1 I dont care 
user2  Fried eggs
User3 it should be ok 
User4 I do not like his assumptions 
User4 I hate rugby
```

I have a model and its 3 cluster centroids and I would like to calculate the distance between each "text" and the centroids. The code words so far but the problem I'm facing is getting averages of similarities per user.e.g.

```
user1 legit thank later
Distance to cluster 0.3
Distance to cluster 0.6
Distance to cluster 0.4

user1 I dont care 
Distance to cluster 0.1
Distance to cluster 0.9
Distance to cluster 0.80

user2  Fried eggs
Distance to cluster 0.4
Distance to cluster 0.4
Distance to cluster 0.33

User3 it should be ok
Distance to cluster 0.4
Distance to cluster 0.54
Distance to cluster 0.6

User4 I do not like his assumptions
Distance to cluster 0.3
Distance to cluster 0.34
Distance to cluster 0.1

User4 I hate rugby
Distance to cluster 0.6
Distance to cluster 0.4
Distance to cluster 0.5
```

Ideally I would like an output for say user one to be as below:

```
user1 legit thank later
Distance to cluster 0.3
Distance to cluster 0.75
Distance to cluster 0.6
```

which is the average of each distance. User 1 has two "texts" so values the sum of each distance to each cluster is divided by 2. User 4 would be divided by 2 also and users 2 and 3 remaining as they are.

Looking forward to your responses.

Comment: I think without any useful code the naming of your dataframe as well as printing the results is of no use and gives no point to start from